# Extending automorphisms to blowup

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've seen versions of this question elsewhere, but I'm not sure if any of them address my specific situation.

**Setup**: $V$ is a normal irreducible algebraic variety of dim > 1 over a field $k$. Let $G < \text{Aut}(V)$ be a group of automorphisms of $V$. Can assume $G$ finite if necessary.

**Question**: Blow up $V$ along its singular locus $V^{sing}$ to get a variety $\tilde{V}= Bl_{V^{sing}}(V)$. Does the group $G$ extend to a group of automorphisms of $\tilde{V}$? In other words, does blowup along $V^{sing}$ induce an injection $G \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\tilde{V})$? I do not want to assume that $\tilde{V}$ is smooth, but so be it if that is necessary.

**Idea**: Use the universal property of the blowup to lift each element $f$ of $G$ to a morphism $\tilde{V}\rightarrow \tilde{V}$. I believe this lift is

1. uniquely determined and
2. an automorphism

both because it agrees with $f$ on the complement of $V^{sing}$. Any group law that holds among the elements of $G$ should hold in the lift to the blowup $\tilde{V}$ because $V\setminus V^{sing}$ is dense in $\tilde{V}$. Hence there is an injective homorphism $G\rightarrow \text{Aut}(\tilde{V})$.

**Follow-up question**: Assuming that the question can be answered in the affirmative, is the blowup map $\pi: \tilde{V}\rightarrow V$ equivariant with respect to the $G$ action? I believe again the answer is yes because $\pi$ is essentially the identity upon restriction to $V\setminus V^{sing} \subset \tilde{V}$ and hence $\pi\circ \tilde{f} = f\circ \pi$ where $\tilde{f}$ is the lift of $f$.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blowup of an ideal sheaf $I$ is defined as the relative projective spectrum
$$
\mathrm{Bl}_I(X) = \mathrm{Proj}_X 
\Big( \bigoplus_{k = 0}^\infty I^k \Big).
$$
If $I$ is invariant under the action of $G$, then the algebra
$$
\bigoplus_{k = 0}^\infty I^k
$$
has a $G$-equivariant structure (induced by the equivariant structure of $\mathcal{O}_X$), which gives an action of $G$ on the projective spectrum.

In your case the ideal of the singular locus is $G$-invariant, hence the above argument applies and proves that $G$ acts on its blowup.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I suppose it is the proj description that gives the universal property after all. I believe that my follow-up question can therefore be answered in the affirmative. Is that correct? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, sure, the blowup morphism is equivariant.

Comment: Greatl, thanks.